# UWP/WinRT: How to scroll a RichEditBox to the cursor position?

Tags: windows-runtime, win-universal-app, scrollviewer, richeditbox

I've implemented a find function on a RichEditBox that when executed will search for `query` and select the found text inside the RichEditBox:

```
String^ docText;
currentRichEditBox->Document->GetText(Text::TextGetOptions::None, &docText);
start = currentRichEditBox->Document->Selection->EndPosition;
end = docText->Length();
int result = newRange->FindText(query, end-start, Text::FindOptions::None);
if (result != 0)
{
    currentRichEditBox->Document->Selection->SetRange(newRange->StartPosition, newRange->EndPosition);
}
```

This works, in that the text that is found is properly selected. However, for a RichEditBox whose contents are so long as to scroll, this will be off-screen and the RichEditBox won't scroll to bring it into view. Oddly enough, however, if this code is re-run then it'll scroll into view the previous result. For example, take the following text:

> This is a test
>
> [Screen end]
>
> 1 hat
>
> 2 hat

When my code searches for hat, it will successfully highlight the first instance of the word hat. However, the RichEditBox won't scroll down to it, even though it's off-screen. The second time the code is run, it will both highlight the second instance and scroll the screen down to the first instance of the word hat.

I am assuming there is a bug in the code for RichEditBox that is causing this. Is there any programmatic way I can manually scroll the RichEditBox or its implicit ScrollViewer to bring the caret into view?

Comment: Have you tried [`ITextRange.ScrollIntoView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.text.itextrange.scrollintoview.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1)?

Comment: @WiredPrairie Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To scroll the highlighted text into position, you'll need to use the [`ScrollIntoView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.text.itextrange.scrollintoview.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1) method available on the `ITextRange` interface.